# My reactjs app didn't open in incognito tab or new browsers and show this errors

Tags: reactjs, deployment, redux

I am new in react/redux and trying to deploy my first application but after deploying it I see some unknowing errors, the app open in my chrome normally without errors, but its showing errors in the incognito tab and also in the other persons normal browsers and showing this errors, also i can't deploy my app in this case :( I need help please.

[click here to see a screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Rrf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the image here https://prnt.sc/l0w8nh
I think If you are using redux dev tools with your app in production environment will be your problem and you have to disable it if environment isn't in development.

And you can see that in action in this repo
 https://github.com/mohamedGamalAbuGalala/burger-builder
And the app is deployed successfully here 
https://react-galala-burger.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

I assume your browser is picking things from cache as it is not opening in your incognito and others browser as well.
Coming to your error you need to check your createStore method. 
Your enhancer should be your third argument always. Please check if the correct parameters are being passed in right place.

createStore expects to receive the following arguments:

reducer (Function): A reducing function that returns the next state tree, given the current state tree and an action to handle.
[preloadedState] (any): The initial state. You may optionally specify it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to restore a previously serialized user session. If you produced reducer with combineReducers, this must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything that your reducer can understand.

[enhancer] (Function): The store enhancer. You may optionally specify it to enhance the store with third-party capabilities such as middleware, time travel, persistence, etc. The only store enhancer that ships with Redux is applyMiddleware().

Remember the root reducer in your app should combine all your reducers into one single reducer.

From the Redux docs

Comment: this is my create store method : `const store = createStoreWithFirebase(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);` i cant recognize the error

Comment: this was an problem with earlier versions of reduxReactFireBase.
are we using the correct versions.
https://github.com/tiberiuc/redux-react-firebase/issues/36

Comment: I tried this way but I got another error `error: v2.0.0-beta and higher require passing a firebase app instance or a firebase library instance. view the migration guide for details.` so is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I figured out that I had some wrong configurations of react-redux dev tools.

I changed the redux store configuration to:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk);

const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, composeWithDevTools(middleware));

export default store;
```